# How to compare two arrays in aws redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to look for if item(s) of array1 is present in array2.

I tried following things:

```
select array('a','b','c') @> array('a','b','c','d');
select array('a','b','c') && array('a','b','c','d');
```

But @> and && operators are not available in redshift.

Is there any work around to achieve this?
Thank you